# Nandroid backup of Emulator instance?

Tags: backup, android-emulator, nandroid

Is it possible to use Nandroid to backup an AVD instance?

Comment: should be, but why not just use the built in snapshot system?

Comment: An AVD instance can be backed up, found in hidden directory called `.android/avd`..

Comment: Because I would extract the system.img of the Nandroid backup and use it to create other AVD instances based on that backup.
If I use the snapshot function I am not sure I can create new virtual devices with different HW and the same system image.

Comment: I've been looking into the `.android/avd/` folder, but I didn't actually find any `system.img` file. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The system images `system.img` are located in the android SDK install directory under `system-images/android-<platform-version>/<platform-type>`.

Once you create the AVD, in the `%USERPROFILE%/.android/avd/<AVD_NAME>.avd` you will find the img files for `/sdcard/` and `/data/`, but `/system` and such are loaded from the SDK path mentioned above.

In order to create an AVD you must install the system images from the SDK manager.

Comment: Ok, thanks for this clarification.
Anyway I still don't get how I could for example install one application in the emulator, save its current state (the system state, i.e. the `system.img` file, I guess) and use it to create a new AVD.
With the `system.img` I could just put it in one of the `android-sdk/platforms/android-XX/images` folders, and create a new AVD with that platform to have an exact system replication...

Comment: you would basically copy the sdcard.img and userdata.img between the instances of the AVD.

Comment: Ok, I got where I was wrong. I was trying to backup the `system.img` file with Nandroid, while I actually needed the `userdata-qemu.img` file and I can easily grab it in the AVD folder. Thanks for your help.